# Floating issue with my ul list

Tags: html, css

I have a question regarding the ul list

I have something like

```
<div>
    <ul id='login'>
        <li>button1</li>
        <li>button2</li>
        <li>button13</li>                
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want them float to the right side of the page

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                              button1 button2 button3 |
|                              
|
```

my css

```
#login li{
    display: inline;
    text-align: right;
}
```

It turns out like

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                              button3 button2 button1 
|                              
|
```

I can simply do the following but I don't want to change the order in html.

```
  <div>
            <ul id='login'>
                <li>button3</li>
                <li>button2</li>
                <li>button11</li>                
            </ul>
  </div>
```

Is there anyway to fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest not floating anything, and just using `text-align` to place the `inline-block` elements against the right-side of the screen:

```
#login {
    text-align: right;
}

#login li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rQJDc/).

Comment: crap, sorry I think that was me, and it was inteded as an upvote. if you change your answer slightly I will fix it, but the vote is locked now! I just suddently noticed that my rep what a point lower and looked in my history to see a downvote... Sorry again.

Comment: heh, sorted. first time I have downvoted accidentally! more attention needed.

Comment: No problem; I don't actually *mind* being down-voted, it's the lack of explanation that bugs me, especially if there's something I can potentially learn from the person that down-voted. In this case, though, I'm okay with the accidental! It's quite late over here in the UK, too... :D

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
#login {
    display: inline-block; /* ul width adapts to its content */
    float: right;          /* clears unused left space */
    overflow: hidden;      /* Or some other clearfix method */
}

#login li {
    display: inline-block; /* permits further link enhancements: height, margin, etc. */
}
```

[Checkout the example.](http://jsfiddle.net/G2qyb/)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
    #login li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#login {
    margin-left: 50%; //or whatever you like
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5U8x/)